# extra spacing in text html

Tags: html, css

When I display my text from lists using this HTML/CSS There are extra bits of space that are being applied to fill the width, how do I fix that?

**HTML**

```
<ul class = "text_quotes">
    <li class = "quote1"> “text text text text text text text text text text text text text...</li>
    <li class = "quote2"> “text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text...</li>
    <li class = "quote3"> “text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text...</li>
    <li class = "quote4"> “text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text...</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.text_quotes li{
    display:inline block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align:justify;
    font-size: smaller;
    font-style:none;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    float: center;
    font-family: avenir;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    min-height: auto;
    max-height: auto;
}
```

edit: I fixed my errors David, but there are still added spaces much like in word when you apply a size to a paragraph. Forgive me I've never written HTML before, I've only worked in C++, Python, and C. So this is very new to me.

Comment: you probably have more styles being applied from another source or the default browser styling. You need to override it.

Comment: `ul.text_quotes{padding:0}`?

Comment: I think you need to fix all the errors in your CSS first.  `display: inline block` is invalid (should be `inline-block`), `font-style: none` is invalid (should be `normal`), `min-height: auto` is invalid ( should be `0`), `max-height: auto` is invalid (should be `none`).

Comment: `float: center` isn't valid either.  Can you explain what you are expecting to see, based on this: http://jsbin.com/OFulUWi/1/edit, which is your HTML and CSS corrected.

Comment: I'm expecting to see a paragraph of text within a set width. And while I'm getting that, there are random extra spaces between some - not all - words. Instead of text saying "Text Text Text" on the first line it's saying "Text --insert 4 spaces here --text" But then the second line will be correct.

Comment: David I looked at the jsbin, and do you see how the first line of text there is more space applied between the words than on the other lines? I want to know how to not allow that to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly positive you just want to left-align your text, not justify it. So:

```
text-align:left;
```

Comment: If that was the answer, please upvote/select as answer!

Comment: I selected it, but I can't up-vote because I'm new here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options to remove the extra spacing on inline-block elements...

**Option 1**

Remove whitespace around the list items in HTML.

Change:

```
<ul class="text_quotes">
    <li class="quote1">Text</li>
    <li class="quote2">Text</li>
    <li class="quote3">Text</li>
    <li class="quote4">Text</li>
</ul>
```

To:

```
<ul class="text_quotes">
    <li class="quote1">
        Text
    </li><li class="quote2">
        Text
    </li><li class="quote3">
        Text
    </li><li class="quote4">
        Text
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Or**

Apply `font-size: 0;` to the `ul` and reset the font size on the `li` `font-size: 14px;`.

There is a great article here on this phenomenon:

http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block

Answer (score 0):

The problem is connected to the `display: inline-block` property. Assuming that you corrected the errors mentioned by *davidpauljunior*, if you want to preserve the above property, you'll have to remove all white-space from the HTML code, so there should be no space between each *closing* and *opening* `li` tag, like this:

```
<ul class="text_quotes">
    <li class="quote1">
        “text text text text text text text text text text text text text...
    </li><li class="quote2">
        “text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text...
    </li><li class="quote3">
        “text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text...
    </li><li class="quote4">
        “text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text...
    </li>
</ul>
```